# Custom Ribbon Action in Approval Center - Project Online (Jquery)

Tags: project-online, pwa

I need to add a custom button in the pwa Ribbon of Project Online at the Approval Center.
I need this using Jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to add a button, you need to run C# CSOM code, but only once, just to add a button. Of course you can also do that in javascript, but since it's one time operation, may be it's more convenient to use C# code. Besides I will provide you both options.

C#, CSOM:

1. Create console application, install `Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM` nuget package.
2. Add `ribbon.xml` file with below content:

```xml
<CommandUIExtension>
    <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.TaskUpdates.Home.Tasks.Controls._children">
            <Button Id="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.TaskUpdates.Home.Tasks.Greetings"
                                    Command="ShowHelloWorldCommand"
                                    Sequence="55"
                                    Alt="Show Greetings"
                                    Description="Show Greetings"
                                    LabelText="Show Greetings"
                                    ToolTipTitle="Show Greetings"
                                    ToolTipDescription="Show Greetings"
                                        Image32by32="{SiteUrl}/_layouts/15/1033/Images/formatmap32x32.png?rev=23"
                    Image32by32Top="-68"
                    Image32by32Left="-272"
                                    TemplateAlias="o1" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.TaskUpdates.Home.Scaling._children">
            <MaxSize Id="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.TaskUpdates.Home.CustomActionGroup.MaxSize"
                             Sequence="55"
                             GroupId="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.TaskUpdates.Home.CustomActionGroup"
                             Size="Large" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">
            <GroupTemplate Id="Custom.Templates">
                <Layout Title="Large">
                    <Section Type="OneRow">
                        <Row>
                            <ControlRef TemplateAlias="c1" DisplayMode="Large" />
                        </Row>
                    </Section>
                </Layout>
            </GroupTemplate>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.TaskUpdates.Home.Groups._children">
            <Group Id="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.TaskUpdates.Home.CustomActionGroup"
                         Sequence="19"
                         Description="Custom Group Description"
                         Title="Custom Group"
                         Template="Custom.Templates">
                <Controls Id="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.TaskUpdates.Home.CustomActionGroup.Controls">
                    <Button Id="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.TaskUpdates.Home.CustomActionGroup.Greetings"
                                    Command="ShowHelloWorldCommand"
                                    Sequence="55"
                                    Alt="Show Greetings"
                                    Description="Show Greetings"
                                    LabelText="Show Greetings"
                                    ToolTipTitle="Show Greetings"
                                    ToolTipDescription="Show Greetings"
                                     Image32by32="{SiteUrl}/_layouts/15/1033/Images/formatmap32x32.png?rev=23"
                    Image32by32Top="-68"
                    Image32by32Left="-272"
                                    TemplateAlias="c1" />
                </Controls>
            </Group>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
    </CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler
         Command="ShowHelloWorldCommand"
         EnabledScript="return true;"
         CommandAction="javascript:MyApp.greetings()" />
    </CommandUIHandlers>
</CommandUIExtension>
```

`ribbon.xml` contains two custom button definitions - one in custom separate group, the other one in default group.
Here is how it looks like in UI:

[image]

3. Put below code into your console app:

```csharp
var actionName = "Project.Ribbon.Approval.MyButton";

var passWord = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in "your_password") passWord.AppendChar(c);

var creds = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("your_user", passWord);

var clientContext = new ClientContext("https://your_tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/");
clientContext.Credentials = creds;

clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, web => web.UserCustomActions);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

var customAction = clientContext.Web.UserCustomActions.FirstOrDefault(uca => uca.Name == actionName);

//if exists just delete and replace with new version
if (customAction != null)
{
    customAction.DeleteObject();
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}

customAction = clientContext.Web.UserCustomActions.Add();
customAction.Name = actionName;
customAction.Location = "CommandUI.Ribbon";
customAction.CommandUIExtension = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("ribbon.xml"); ; // CommandUIExtension xml
customAction.RegistrationType = UserCustomActionRegistrationType.None;
customAction.Sequence = 1000;

customAction.Update();
clientContext.Load(customAction);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

4. Go to approval center, `sites/pwa/Approvals.aspx`, edit page and add script editor web part. Put the following code inside:

```js
var MyApp = MyApp || {};
MyApp.greetings = function(){
 alert('Hello!');
}
```

5. Click on custom button and you will see the alert.

As promised, javascript (JSOM) version:

```js
var xml = '<CommandUIExtension> <CommandUIDefinitions>      <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.TaskUpdates.Home.Tasks.Controls._children">            <Button Id="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.TaskUpdates.Home.Tasks.Greetings"                                 Command="ShowHelloWorldCommand"                                 Sequence="55"                                   Alt="Show Greetings"                                    Description="Show Greetings"                                    LabelText="Show Greetings"                                  ToolTipTitle="Show Greetings"                                   ToolTipDescription="Show Greetings"                                     Image32by32="{SiteUrl}/_layouts/15/1033/Images/formatmap32x32.png?rev=23"                    Image32by32Top="-68"                    Image32by32Left="-272"                                 TemplateAlias="o1" />       </CommandUIDefinition>      <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.TaskUpdates.Home.Scaling._children">           <MaxSize Id="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.TaskUpdates.Home.CustomActionGroup.MaxSize"                           Sequence="55"                           GroupId="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.TaskUpdates.Home.CustomActionGroup"                          Size="Large" />        </CommandUIDefinition>      <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">         <GroupTemplate Id="Custom.Templates">               <Layout Title="Large">                  <Section Type="OneRow">                     <Row>                           <ControlRef TemplateAlias="c1" DisplayMode="Large" />                       </Row>                  </Section>              </Layout>           </GroupTemplate>        </CommandUIDefinition>      <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.TaskUpdates.Home.Groups._children">            <Group Id="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.TaskUpdates.Home.CustomActionGroup"                         Sequence="19"                       Description="Custom Group Description"                      Title="Custom Group"                        Template="Custom.Templates">               <Controls Id="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.TaskUpdates.Home.CustomActionGroup.Controls">                   <Button Id="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.TaskUpdates.Home.CustomActionGroup.Greetings"                                 Command="ShowHelloWorldCommand"                                 Sequence="55"                                   Alt="Show Greetings"                                    Description="Show Greetings"                                    LabelText="Show Greetings"                                  ToolTipTitle="Show Greetings"                                   ToolTipDescription="Show Greetings"                                  Image32by32="{SiteUrl}/_layouts/15/1033/Images/formatmap32x32.png?rev=23"                    Image32by32Top="-68"                    Image32by32Left="-272"                                    TemplateAlias="c1" />               </Controls>         </Group>        </CommandUIDefinition>  </CommandUIDefinitions> <CommandUIHandlers>     <CommandUIHandler        Command="ShowHelloWorldCommand"         EnabledScript="return true;"        CommandAction="javascript:MyApp.greetings()" />    </CommandUIHandlers></CommandUIExtension>';

SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
    var web = clientContext.get_web(); 
    var userActions = web.get_userCustomActions();
    clientContext.load(userActions);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
        var actions = userActions.getEnumerator();
        while(actions.moveNext()){
            var action = actions.get_current();

            if(action.get_name() === 'Project.Ribbon.Approval.MyButton'){
                //or skip removal and just return, if button exists
                action.deleteObject();
                clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
                    addButton(clientContext, userActions);
                }, function(err){
                    alert(err);
                });
                return;
            }
        }

        addButton(clientContext, userActions);

    }, function(err){
        alert(err);
    });
}, 'sp.js');

function addButton(clientContext, userActions){
    var newUserCustomAction = userActions.add(); 
    newUserCustomAction.set_location('CommandUI.Ribbon'); 
    newUserCustomAction.set_commandUIExtension(xml);
    newUserCustomAction.set_sequence(100); 
    newUserCustomAction.set_name('Project.Ribbon.Approval.MyButton'); 
    newUserCustomAction.update();

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
        alert('Action added!');
    }, function(err){
        alert(err);
    });
}
```